# Backtrack graphics

Tags: linux, graphics

A friend of me want to install BackTrack on his old system (HP Compaq Presario Pentium D). When we type the code 'startx' we've got an error. "Input signal out of range" comes up on the screen. How can we fix that, so we can install Backtrack?

Regards

--EDIT--
The graphics card is an *ATI Radeon Xpress 200*

Comment: Backtrack forums might be the best place to ask this...http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/forum.php

Answer (score 0):

are you using a digital monitor? try changing to analog (vga, svga plug)

Comment: He is using VGA

Comment: try with another display, would be the easy fix. Otherwise look into lowering the resolution for screen.

Comment: He doesnt have an other monitor, but he can using his TV, i think

Comment: You might consider editing your question to include all hardware information.

Comment: The graphics card is an ATI Radeon Xpress 200